# Redux Toolkit: addCase cannot be called with two reducers for the same action type

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm playing around with Redux Toolkit and am getting stumped with async thunk reducers... as far as I can tell this error should only come up if I'm adding two action creators with the same type to the createReducer builder?

actions.js

```
import userServer from './apis/userServer'
import { createAction, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const fetchUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  'FETCH_USERS',
  async () => {
    const res = await userServer.get('/users')
    return res.data
  }
)

export const addUser = createAsyncThunk('ADD_USER', async (data) => {
  const res = await userServer.post('/users', data)
  return res.data
})

export const logIn = createAction('LOG_IN')
export const logOut = createAction('LOG_OUT')
```

reducers.js

```
import { createReducer, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { fetchUsers, addUser, logIn, logOut } from './actions'

const reduceUsers = createReducer([], (builder) => {
  builder
    .addCase(
      (fetchUsers.fulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        console.log(action)
        if (state !== []) state = action
      })
    )
    // no errors if we comment out this case
    .addCase(
      (addUser.fulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        state.users.push(action)
      })
    )
})

const reduceLogin = createReducer(
  { loggedIn: false, user: null },
  (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(logIn, (state, action) => {
        state.loggedIn = true
        state.user = action
      })
      .addCase(logOut, (state) => {
        state.loggedIn = false
        state.user = null
      })
  }
)

export default combineReducers({ users: reduceUsers, login: reduceLogin })
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Very far-fetched thought: are you sure you saved your `actions.ts`? I'd bet there is some old state with the same first argument to `createAsyncThunk` saved on disk.

Comment: Thanks for the thought but yeah I saved.

Answer (score 0):

try using two  separated builder instances
like

```
  const reduceUsers = createReducer([], (builder) => {
      builder
        .addCase(
          (fetchUsers.fulfilled,
          (state, action) => {
            console.log(action)
            if (state !== []) state = action
          })
        )
        
        builder
        .addCase(
          (addUser.fulfilled,
          (state, action) => {
            state.users.push(action)
          })
        )
    })
```

if you still facing the same error try

```
   const reduceUsers = createReducer([], (builder) => {
    const fetchUsersFullfilled = fetchUsers.fulfilled
    const addUserFullfilled = addUser.fulfilled
    
      builder
        .addCase(
          (fetchUsersFullfilled,
          (state, action) => {
            console.log(action)
            if (state !== []) state = action
          })
        )
        .addCase(
          (addUserFullfilled,
          (state, action) => {
            state.users.push(action)
          })
        )
    })
```